# cakephp excel multiple sheets

Tags: excel, cakephp, spreadsheet

I want to output excel file with multiple sheets
I have used https://github.com/segy/PhpExcel component
the following code works fine for me, but I want to output the data array 3    times in 3 sheets. I will have to loop through '$mySheets' but don't know how to combine all sheets and output file all togather.

```
 public function excel(){
    $data=array();
    $data[] =array(
        'name'=>'gyle',
        'type'=>'admin',
        'date'=>'2014-10-12 12:23:12',
        'description'=>'some description',
        'modified'=>'2014-10-12 12:23:12'
        );
    $data[] =array(
        'name'=>'smith',
        'type'=>'admin',
        'date'=>'2014-10-12 12:23:12',
        'description'=>'some description',
        'modified'=>'2014-10-12 12:23:12'
        );

    $mySheets= array("sheet1","sheet2","sheet3");
    // create new empty worksheet and set default font

    $this->PhpExcel->createWorksheet()
        ->setDefaultFont('Calibri', 12);

    // define table cells
    $table = array(
        array('label' => __('name'), 'filter' => true),
        array('label' => __('Type'), 'filter' => true),
        array('label' => __('Date')),
        array('label' => __('Description'), 'width' => 50, 'wrap' => true),
        array('label' => __('Modified'))
    );

    // add heading with different font and bold text
    $this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'Cambria', 'bold' => true));

    // add data
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $this->PhpExcel->addTableRow(array(
            $d['name'],
            $d['type'],
            $d['date'],
            $d['description'],
            $d['modified']
        ));
    }
    // close table and output
    $this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter()->output();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, using the function createSheet after createWorksheet this an example :

```
<?php 

$this->PhpExcel->createWorksheet();
$this->PhpExcel->setDefaultFont('Calibri', 12);

//FIRST SHEET
$this->PhpExcel->createSheet();
$this->PhpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$this->PhpExcel->setWorksheetName("FIRST");

$table = array(
        array('label' => __('Name'), 'width' => 'auto'),
        array('label' => __('Surname'), 'width' => 'auto'),
        array('label' => __('Tel'), 'width' => 'auto'),
        '',
    );
$this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'DATA', 'bold' => true));

$row = array('PEPE','BOTICA', '654654654');
$this->PhpExcel->addTableRow($row);
(...)//More rows

$this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter();


//SECOND SHEET

$this->PhpExcel->createSheet();
$this->PhpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$this->PhpExcel->setWorksheetName("SECOND");
$this->PhpExcel->setRow(1); //reset the row number

$table = array(
array('label' => __('Nº'), 'width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
array('label' => __('Question'), 'width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
array('label' => __('Response'), 'width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
array('label' => __(''), 'width' => 'auto'),
);

$this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'PREGUNTAS', 'bold' => true));
$row = array('1','Oficio', 'Honrado traf...');
$this->PhpExcel->addTableRow($row);
(...)//More rows

$this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter();


$this->PhpExcel->output('MyMultipleSheets.xlsx');       

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this works for me ===>
<?php $this->PhpExcel->createWorksheet()
                    ->setDefaultFont('Calibri', 12);

$this->PhpExcel->createSheet();
$this->PhpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->PhpExcel->setWorksheetName("System Unit/Laptop");

                $table = array(
                        array('label' => __('Category'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Item Name'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('PC-Name'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Serial #'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('CPU'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Status'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Motherboard'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true','filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Processor'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Memory'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Video Card'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true','filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('HDD'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('OS'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Product key'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Location'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Department'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('User'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Remarks'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Comment'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),


                     );
                $this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'Cambria', 'bold' => true));  

                 foreach ($data as $item) {

                    if ($item['Category']['category_id'] == '1' || $item['Category']['category_id'] == '3'){
                    $this->PhpExcel->addTableRow(array(

                        $item['Category']['category_name'] ,
                        $item['Item']['item_property_number'],
                        $item['Item']['item_name'],
                        $item['Item']['item_serial_number'],
                        $item['Item']['item_cpu'],
                        $item['Item']['item_model'],
                        $item['Item']['item_mom'],
                        $item['Item']['item_processor'],
                        $item['Item']['item_memory'],
                        $item['Item']['item_vidcard'],
                        $item['Item']['item_su_hd'],
                        $item['Item']['item_su_os'],
                        $item['Item']['item_key'],
                        $item['Item']['item_floor'],
                        $item['Item']['item_dept'],
                        $item['Employee']['employee_lastname'],
                        $item['Item']['item_status'] ? 'Serviceable' : 'Unusable',
                        $item['Item']['item_comment']
                    ));
                }
            }

             $this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter();


$this->PhpExcel->createSheet();
$this->PhpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(01);
$this->PhpExcel->setWorksheetName("Others");
$this->PhpExcel->setRow(1);


$table2 = array(
                        array('label' => __('Category'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Item Name'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('PC-Name'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Serial #'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Location'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Department'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('User'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Remarks'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Comment'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),

    );
                 $this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table2, array('name' => 'Cambria', 'bold' => true));

                 foreach ($data as $item) {
                    if ($item['Category']['category_id'] == '2' || $item['Category']['category_id'] >= '4'){
                    $this->PhpExcel->addTableRow(array(

                        $item['Category']['category_name'],
                        $item['Item']['item_property_number'],
                        $item['Item']['item_name2'],
                        $item['Item']['item_serial_number'],
                        $item['Item']['item_floor'],
                        $item['Item']['item_dept'],
                        $item['Employee']['employee_lastname'],
                        $item['Item']['item_status'] ? 'Serviceable' : 'Unusable',
                        $item['Item']['item_comment']

                    ));
                }
            }

            $this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter();

$this->PhpExcel->createSheet();
$this->PhpExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(02);
$this->PhpExcel->setWorksheetName("Repair History");
$this->PhpExcel->setRow(1);

           $table = array(
                        array('label' => __('Repair ID'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => 'Monitor'),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Item'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Pre-Date'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Local #'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Pre-Findings'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Pre-Recom'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Pre Eu Rep'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Pre It Rep'),'wrap' => 'true','width' => 'auto', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Pre Admin Rep'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Post Date'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Post Findings'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Post Recom'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Post  Eu Rep'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Post  It Rep'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Post Admin Rep'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Manner'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Date Pullout'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Date Returned'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Item Condition'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Cost'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),
                        array('label' => __('Repair Status'),'width' => 'auto','wrap' => 'true', 'filter' => true),



    );

                     $this->PhpExcel->addTableHeader($table, array('name' => 'Cambria', 'bold' => true));

                                     foreach ($itemRepair as $item) {

                                        $this->PhpExcel->addTableRow(array(

                                            $item['Repair']['repair_id'],
                                            $item['Item']['item_property_number'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_pre_date'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_local_no'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_pre_findings'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_pre_recom'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_pre_eu_rep'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_pre_it_rep'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_pre_admin_rep'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_post_date'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_post_findings'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_post_recom'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_post_eu_rep'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_post_it_rep'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_post_admin_rep'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_manner']? 'In-house': 'Outsource' ,
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_date_pullout'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_date_returned'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_item_condition'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_cost'],
                                            $item['Repair']['repair_status'] ? 'Serviceable':'Unusable'  ,
                                        ));

                                }



                $this->PhpExcel->addTableFooter()
                    ->output();




?>
```